# Running an .exe on cmd line from a visual studio c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cmd, ffmpeg

**BACKGROUND**

I have a visual studio c++ project "VideoAnalyser" which analyses a video for specific features based predominantly on OPENCV.

I now want to run this project against a large directory of video files. The issue I have is that they must first be converted to .avi file format in order to utilise the OPENCV functions within my project. I can do this with FFMPEG. It is a large directory and i do not want to create duplicates of every video file with the format changed. Rather, I'd take the video file, convert it, then run the "Video Analyser" against it destroy the reformatted file and then move onto the next video file and repeat. I can run FFMPEG independantly on the command line with no issues, however I'm unsure how to integrate this into my "Video Analyser" project which leads to...

**MY QUESTION**

How do I get my "VideoAnalyser" c++ project to run the FFMPEG exectuable through the cmd line?

Comment: Use `system()`??

Comment: @user0042 Im fairly new to this, so unaware of features like this. I'll look into it, thankyou for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows OS, since you tagged `cmd`. You can do that starting another process. So, given the command line:

```
int StartProcess(const std::wstring &executableName, bool wait, bool showConsole)
{
    std::wstring executableName_local(executableName);

    DWORD rtv = 0;
    STARTUPINFOW sti;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&sti, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    BOOL ok = CreateProcess(NULL, (LPWSTR) executableName_local.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, showConsole ? CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE : CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &sti, &pi);

    if (ok == FALSE)
        return -1;

    if (wait)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &rtv);
        if (rtv)
            return -1;
    }
    return (int)rtv;
}
```

(not tested: copy/pasted from my code)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is look for the c methods popen and system.

Comment: `popen` is not C, but POSIX. Msvc has _popen instead.

Comment: Agreed, but then I expect the OP would be happy once they have read the docs for _popen that a search for popen will find. Probably system is the call they want anyway, but the choice is there,